# Clearing a selected item in dropdown after selecting item in other dropdown with vue-treeselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-treeselect

I'm coding about auto select provinces in Thailand, When I choose province A in **province dropdown** the **district dropdown** will change to value in province A, and when I change to province B in **province dropdown** value in **district dropdown** has changed to district in province B already but the UI of **district dropdown** still shows district in province A.

I have researched treeselect docs and tried for several days now, and I really can't find a solution :-(

[This is UI rightnow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF6cN.jpg)

```
<treeselect 
    id="province-selected"
    v-model="state.provinceSelected" 
    :options="provinceArr" 
    placeholder="กรุณาเลือกจังหวัด" 
    noResultsText="ไม่พบข้อมูล"
    data-test="province-input"
    :class="{ errorselect: v$.provinceSelected.$errors.length }"
    :normalizer="normalizerProvince"
    @select="getDistrict"
    zIndex="20000"
    :clearable="false"
    :allowClearingDisabled="true"
/>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation of [`VueTreeselect`](https://vue-treeselect.js.org/#events) mentions, the `select` event is **Emitted after selecting an option.** It has no dependency with the value update. I prefer you to use `input` event instead of `select`. Because the documentation states, the `input` event will be **Emitted after value changes.** So inside this method you will get the updated value for the first select.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
Vue.component('treeselect', VueTreeselect.Treeselect)
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        provinceArr: [
            { id: 1, label: 'Province 1', districtArr: [
                { id: 10, label: 'District 01' },
                { id: 11, label: 'District 02' },
                { id: 12, label: 'District 03' },
                { id: 13, label: 'District 04' },
            ]},
            { id: 2, label: 'Province 2', districtArr: [
                { id: 20, label: 'District 21' },
                { id: 21, label: 'District 22' },
                { id: 22, label: 'District 23' },
                { id: 23, label: 'District 24' },
            ]},
            { id: 3, label: 'Province 3', districtArr: [
                { id: 30, label: 'District 31' },
                { id: 31, label: 'District 32' },
                { id: 32, label: 'District 33' },
                { id: 33, label: 'District 34' },
            ] },
            { id: 4, label: 'Province 4', districtArr: [
                { id: 40, label: 'District 41' },
                { id: 41, label: 'District 42' },
                { id: 42, label: 'District 43' },
                { id: 43, label: 'District 44' },
            ] },
            { id: 5, label: 'Province 5', districtArr: [
                { id: 50, label: 'District 51' },
                { id: 51, label: 'District 52' },
                { id: 52, label: 'District 53' },
                { id: 53, label: 'District 54' },
            ] },
            { id: 6, label: 'Province 6', districtArr: [
                { id: 60, label: 'District 61' },
                { id: 61, label: 'District 62' },
                { id: 72, label: 'District 73' },
                { id: 73, label: 'District 74' },
            ] },
        ],
        districtArr: [],
        state: {
            provinceSelected: null,
            districtSelected: null,
        },
    },
    methods: {
        getDistrict: function(node, instanceId) {
            console.log(this.state.provinceSelected, node, instanceId);
            // Some logic to populate districts
            this.districtArr = this.provinceArr.find(item => item.id === this.state.provinceSelected).districtArr;
        },
        onDistrictSelected: function(node, instanceId) {
            console.log(this.state.districtSelected)
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<!-- include Vue 2.x -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^2"></script>
<!-- include vue-treeselect & its styles. you can change the version tag to better suit your needs. -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@riophae/vue-treeselect@^0.4.0/dist/vue-treeselect.umd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@riophae/vue-treeselect@^0.4.0/dist/vue-treeselect.min.css">
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <p>Province</p>
        <treeselect 
            id="province-selected"
            v-model="state.provinceSelected" 
            :options="provinceArr" 
            placeholder="กรุณาเลือกจังหวัด" 
            noResultsText="ไม่พบข้อมูล"
            data-test="province-input"
            @input="getDistrict"
            zIndex="20000"
            :clearable="false"
            :allowClearingDisabled="true"
        />
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>District</p>
        <treeselect 
            id="district-selected"
            v-model="state.districtSelected" 
            :options="districtArr" 
            placeholder="กรุณาเลือกจังหวัด" 
            noResultsText="ไม่พบข้อมูล"
            data-test="district-input"
            @input="onDistrictSelected"
            zIndex="20000"
            :clearable="false"
            :allowClearingDisabled="true"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```